# CORS request with golang backend doesn't works

Tags: http, go, cors

I'm facing some issue with my implementation.
I have a backend written in Golang and the UI (in Angular2) which are on the same server.

I've tried to set the CORS handling in my backend but it still doesn't work and I'm not getting why.

Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
)

var router *mux.Router

func main() {
    router = mux.NewRouter()

    HandleFuncEx("/authentication", handleAuthentication)
    HandleFuncEx("/callA", handleCallA)
    HandleFuncEx("/callB", handleCallB)
    HandleFuncEx("/callC", handleCallC)

    handler := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"},
        AllowedMethods: []string{"GET", "POST", "PATCH"},
        AllowedHeaders: []string{"a_custom_header", "content_type"},
    }).Handler(router)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", handler)

}

func HandleFuncEx(pattern string, handler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) {
    log.Println("handled function", pattern)
    router.HandleFunc(pattern, handler)
}
```

The authentication pattern works correctly (is the first called by the UI)
all the others calls fails the preflight request.
Why is it happening?

Thanks everybody for the help!

EDIT:

This is an example of a non-working response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Date: Fri, 07 Apr 2017 08:33:12 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

And these are request's headers:

```
OPTIONS /users HTTP/1.1
Host: /* Removed by my company policy */
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: /* Removed by my company policy */
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access_token
Accept: */*
Referer: /* Removed by my company policy */
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,it;q=0.4,la;q=0.2
```

Comment: can you share a chrome devtools screenshot of the options request that is failing, request sent, response received?

Comment: CORS uses a probe request using the OPTIONS verb to check if cross-origin is allowed, before executing the actual request. You must allow OPTIONS and respond to it with a success code (2xx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7426/adrian) pointed out, you need to add the `OPTIONS` Method to the `AllowedMethods` array.

Please also consider to add `Accept`, `Accept-Language` and `Content-Type` to the `AllowedHeaders` as good practice.

If you don't want to use the `github.com/rs/cors` package, you can write a simple CORS decorator middleware on your own like this:

**CORS decorator**

```
import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

// CORSRouterDecorator applies CORS headers to a mux.Router
type CORSRouterDecorator struct {
    R *mux.Router
}

// ServeHTTP wraps the HTTP server enabling CORS headers.
// For more info about CORS, visit https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/
func (c *CORSRouterDecorator) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    if origin := req.Header.Get("Origin"); origin != "" {
        rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
        rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
        rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Type, YourOwnHeader")
    }
    // Stop here if its Preflighted OPTIONS request
    if req.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        return
    }

    c.R.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
}
```

**HTTP server**

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.Handle("/authentication", handleAuthentication)

http.Handle("/", &CORSRouterDecorator{r})
```

et voilà.

Comment: the default settings using rs/cors  didn't work for me. this was the only code that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I use Negroni as middleware and this code:

```
func main() {

    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"},
        AllowedMethods: []string{"POST", "GET", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "DELETE"},
        AllowedHeaders: []string{"Accept", "content-type", "Content-Length", "Accept-Encoding", "X-CSRF-Token", "Authorization"},
    })

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router = routers.SetAuthRoute(router)

    apiRoutes := routers.InitRoutes()

    router.PathPrefix("/api").Handler(negroni.New(
        negroni.HandlerFunc(controllers.ValidateTokenMiddleware),
        negroni.Wrap(apiRoutes),
    ))

    server := negroni.Classic()
    server.Use(c)
    server.UseHandler(router)
    server.Run("0.0.0.0:" + os.Getenv("PORT"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other two responses, but I my case my project is hosted on cloud9 so I had a couple of tweaks to do.

This is the code i added:

```
    cor := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins:   []string{"https://*.c9users.io", "http://myapp.c9users.io:8080", "https://*.c9.io"},
        AllowedMethods:   []string{"POST", "GET", "OPTIONS", "PUT"},
        AllowedHeaders:   []string{"Accept", "Accept-Language", "Content-Type"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        Debug:            true,
    });
```

I had to add the extra http origin as Safari makes the initial options request using http instead of https.

Sorted.